# scala twitter streaming: melting tuple of tuples

Tags: scala, twitter, mapreduce

I'm new to scala, and learning how to process twitter streams with scala.
I've been playing with the sample code below and trying to modify it to do some other stuffs.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/TwitterPopularTags.scala#L60

I have a tuple of tuples(maybe tuple is not the exact type name in scala streaming but..) summarizes each tweet like this: (username, (tuple of hashtags), (tuple of users mentioned in this tweet))

And below is the code I used to make this.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterPopularTags")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(duration.toInt))
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)

// record username, hashtags, and mentioned user
val distilled = stream.map(status => (status.getUser.getName, status.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")), status.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("@"))))
```

What I want to do is melt this tuple into (tag, user, (mentioned users)).
For example, if the original tuple was

```
(Tom, (#apple, #banana), (@Chris, @Bob))
```

I want the result to be

```
((#apple, Tom, (@Chris, @Bob)), (#banana, Tom, (@Chris, @Bob))
```

My goal is to run reduceByKey on this result using the hashtag as the key to get

```
(#apple, (list of users who tweeted this hashtag), (list of users who were mentioned in tweets with this hashtag))
```

I'm not sure 'melt' is the right term to use for this purpose but just think of it as similar to melt function in R. Is there a way to get this done using .map{case ... } or .flatMap{case ... }? Or do I have to define a function to do this job?

---

ADDED reduce question:

As I said I want to reduce the result with reduceByKeyAndWindow so I wrote the following code:

```
// record username, hashtags, and mentioned user
val distilled = stream.map(
  status => (status.getUser.getName,
  status.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")),
  status.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("@")))
)

val byTags = distilled.flatMap{
  case (user, tag, mentioned) => tag.map((_ -> List(1, List(user), mentioned)))
}.reduceByKeyAndWindow({
  case (a, b) => List(a._1+b._1, a._2++b._2, a._3++b._3)}, Seconds(60), Seconds(duration.toInt)
)

val sorted = byTags.map(_.flatten).map{
  case (tag, count, users, mentioned) => (count, tag, users, mentioned)
}.transform(_.sortByKey(false))

// Print popular hashtags
sorted.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  val topList = rdd.take(num.toInt)
  println("\n%d Popular tags in last %d seconds:".format(num.toInt, duration.toInt))
  topList.foreach{case (count, tag, users, mentioned) => println("%s (%s tweets), authors: %s, mentioned: %s".for$
})
```

However, it says

```
  missing parameter type for expanded function
[error] The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
[error] Expected type was: ?
[error]     }.reduceByKeyAndWindow({
```

I've tried deleting the brackets and cases, writing (a:List, b:List) =>, but all of them gave me errors related with types. What is the correct way to reduce it so that users and mentioned will be concatenated every 'duration' seconds for 60 secs?

Answer (score 0):

```
hashTags.flatMap{ case (user, tags, mentions) => tags.map((_, user,mentions))}
```

The most trouble thing in your question is the misusing of term `tuple`.

In python `tuple` means immutable type which could have any size.

In scala `TupleN` means immutable type with N type parameters contains exactly N members of corresponding types. So `Tuple2` is not the same the `Tuple3`.

In scala which is full of immutable types, any immutable collection like [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List), [`Vector`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector) or [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) could be considered as analogue of python's `tuple`. But most precise are probably subtype of [`immutable.IndexedSeq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq) e.g. [`Vector`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector)

So methods like `String.splitAt` never could return a `Tuple` in scala sense, simply because element count could not be known at compile time.

At that concrete case result will be simply [`Array][5]`. And such assumption i used in my answer.

But in case if you will really have collection (i.e. `RDD`) of type `(String, (String, String), (String, String))` you can use this almost equivalent piece of code

```
hashTags.flatMap {
  case (user, (tag1, tag2), mentions) => Seq(tag1, tag2).map((_, user, mentions))
}
```